# Find common elements in k sorted lists (assuming they can have duplicate values) in constant space

Tags: java, algorithm

I was wondering what is the most efficient solution to find intersection of k sorted lists of integers (assuming that they can have duplicates). I have already came up with a few solutions. But I was wondering if there is any way to do it in constant space and with best time complexity?

```
Ex:
for k=4
[[1,2,3,3,4],[2,3,3,5],[1,2,3,3,5,6,7],[1,2,3,3,6,7,8,9]]
should return [2,3,3]
```

Comment: Do you want actual code here or just a description of the algorithm?

Comment: Is "intersection" have to be contiguous or not? ex: if [1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,2,3,4], then [2, 3, 4] or [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Java code would be better.

Comment: square1001 being continues does not matter in your example answer should be [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general algorithm which would not require any additional space except for storing the common elements found.

```
Place pointers at the start of each of the N arrays

Then repeat the following
    Check if all N elements are the same
    If yes, then
        Advance all N pointers by one
    If no, then
        Advance only the pointer of the smallest value
    Repeat this until all elements have been exhausted
```

Comment: How does that touch each element once? Suppose some but not all of the N elements are the same. Now we advance the smallest element. How many previously examined elements do we compare the new element with? (Also, how do you discover which element is now the smallest?) ... of course, you could use a heap ...

Comment: In java you need to store those pointers in a array which means your space complexity would be O(K)

Answer (score 1):

**In-place approach**

You can use slightly changed in-place merge algorithm of two sorted arrays for finding an intersection in-place. We will have `N-1` (`N` is the number of arrays) iterations. On every iteration we will merge first array with array with `i+1` index. The result will be written in the first array. Something like this:

http://ideone.com/NQznBV

```
private static int intersect(int[] a, int alen, int[] b) {
    int resLen = 0, bIndex = 0;
    for (int aIndex = 0; aIndex < alen; ++aIndex) {
        while (bIndex < b.length && a[aIndex] > b[bIndex]) ++bIndex;
        if (bIndex == b.length) break;

        if (a[aIndex] == b[bIndex]) {
            a[resLen] = a[aIndex];
            ++resLen;
            ++bIndex;
        }
    }
    return resLen;
}

private static int intersectArrays(int[][] arrays) {
    int len = arrays[0].length;
    for (int i = 1; i < arrays.length; ++i) {
        len = intersect(arrays[0], len, arrays[i]);
    }
    return len;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[][] arr = {{1,2,3,3,4},{2,3,3,5},{1,2,3,3,5,6,7},{1,2,3,3,6,7,8,9}};
    int len = intersectArrays(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        System.out.print(arr[0][i] + " ");
}
```

As a result we have constant additional space and linear time complexity.

**Another approach**

If we cannot change the input, we can use another algorithm.

First of all, let's take the first number of the first array (`current`).

Then for every array we can find number of occurrences of this `current` number in the array (this can be done with two binary searches). Then output this number "minimal occurrence" times.

Then we will find next number (greater than previous) in the first array (also with binary search), and so on.

Time complexity of this algorithm will depend on number of different values in first array (`D`). And it will be equal to `O(D*N*logK)`, where K - maximal length of arrays. It worth noting that this algorithm could be much faster than in-place algorithm above in some cases.

Comment: Seems correct but is it ok to change the input? and does the fact that we are storing merged array in first array make it constant space algorithm? In this case time complexity would be O(KN)? K # arrays N# length of each array?

Comment: @sepi It would be impossible to get constant space if we cannot change input, because we need additional memory to store the result, which is not constant. And time complexity is O(n), where n is the sum of array's length. If all of them have identical length K, then, yes, O(N*K).

Comment: @sepi "and does the fact that we are storing merged array in first array make it constant space algorithm?" Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that we would need to use memory to return the results and that is not considered as extra space. I was just not sure if for example during the interview we are allowed to change the input.

Comment: I think there is a solution using binary search but the time complexity would be much higher

Comment: @sepi Added another approach

Comment: This is one of the solutions I implemented. I have a question how would you handle not adding occurrence for duplicate values in first array? I mean if we have {2,2} in all rays then {2,2} will be added two times to output. Output will have {2,2,2,2}

Comment: @sepi I will take 2 only once on the first step, then I'll find greater number using binary search

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map to count your array content and afterwards check which numbers meet your condition.

```
    int[][] input = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}};
    int k = 4;

    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    for (int[] oneArray : input) {
        for (int oneNumber : oneArray) {
            counter.merge(oneNumber, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> countEntry : counter.entrySet()) {
        if (countEntry.getValue() % k == 0) {
            int numberOfHits = countEntry.getValue() / k;
            for (int kCount = 0; kCount < numberOfHits; kCount++) {
                System.out.println(countEntry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible that one array has three entries for 3 and the other has one entry for 3 in this case your algorithm would assume that each of them has two entries for 3, which is not correct. Also can you explain more about your merge function? Also I do not understand how the map would only contain the common values as its keys. Finally, I do not think this is a constant space algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of duplicates in any of the lists is more than half the list's length, we can do it with less space than initially given :)

Convert that list to a hash map, where the key is the list's element and the value is a tuple: `{count, intersection_count, k_count}`.

Now traverse the rest of the lists: if the element seen is a key in the list-converted-to-hash-map, set `intersection_count` to `min(count-in-current-list, intersection_count)` and increment `k_count`.

Comment: @ גלעד ברקן What about the values in the first list that are not present in other lists?In this case final map would contain those values as well. It will not contain only the common values as its keys. Also using hash map still has O(N) space complexity.

Comment: @sepi, thank you for your comment. The final intersection will be composed of those records in `list-converted-to-hash-map` that have a `k_count` equal to `k`. The hash map will take up `O(n)` space where `n` is the number of unique elements in the list we convert.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing each list of data as a set or multiset, instead of a list.  Sets have a built-in, efficient way of finding intersections of sets.